# GLM or GLMM design for different tasks

Tags: r, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, glmm

I am conducting a study involving 70 participants diagnosed with Mild Cognitive Impairment (MCI) and 75 without MCI. All participants were engaged in taxonomic semantic, thematic semantic, and phonemic fluency tasks, where they were asked to articulate as many words as possible related to the categories ‘animals’, ‘supermarket’, and starting with the phoneme /p/, respectively. For each task, I collected identical features (e.g., average number of syllables, average concreteness, etc.), resulting in each participant having three values per feature (one for each task).

I am interested in identifying which specific feature, associated with a particular task, exhibits a significant difference in predicting group membership. Additionally, I intend to control for age, sex, and education variables as covariates in this analysis

Which is the optimal modeling approach between GLM and GLMM for this scenario? Additionally, could someone assist by providing R code? I'm new to this and eager to learn.

Comment: The analysis will not be very stable/powerful with a dichotomous trait.  You will get much better results if you analyze the **degree** of cognitive impairment.

Comment: Thank you for this advice! Keeping that in mind, would you be able to assist me with the initial questions?

Comment: The data need to be repaired first.

Comment: Yes! I have the Mattis score, so I can replace the diagnosis by the degree of cognitive impairment. I am not sure if I should use GLM or GLMM for this

Comment: It depends on the distribution.  If it’s lumpy or has floor or ceiling effects an ordinal regression model should be considered.  See fharrell.com/post/rpo